# Updating collection(s) in Firebase that are created w/Cloud Functions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

**Be advised, the following scenario uses Cloud Firestore**.

Within my Cloud Functions `index.js`, I have a function, `createUserAccount`, that adds a newly created user to a `users` collection and sets fields for their email, photo, favorites (this is a feature in the application that does not need to be elaborated on), and some other distinct fields for a user. The function is triggered upon successful completion of the the following code snippet:

```
// The following method has been simplified to focus on the problem statement
public void createAccountWithEmailAndPassword(String username, String displayName,
                                              String someOtherImportantThing) {

    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), task -> {
                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:Success");
                        onSuccess.updateAccount(displayName, username);
                        updateUsernameProperty(username);
                        onBackPressed();
                    } else {
                          if (task.getException() != null) {
                              if (task.getException()
                                      .getMessage()
                                      .contains(EMAIL_EXISTS_ERROR)) {
                                  // Handle Email Exists Error
                              }
                          }
                          Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure",
                                    task.getException());
                    }
                });
     }
```

As you can see, when the task is completed successfully a few methods are called: `updateUsernameProperty(String username)` and `updateAccount(String displayName, username)`

`updateAccount(String displayName)` takes a users chosen displayName and adds this as a field to the users account. **This does not make changes to the users collection - only to the authenticated account**.

`updateUsernameProperty(String username)` takes the users chosen userName and **sets this property as a field within the users document**. Here is the code sample, as it may prove helpful to understanding my problem:

```
private void updateUsernameProperty(String username) {
    DocumentReference docRef = mFirestore
                                  .collection(TABLE_USERS)
                                  .document(mFirebaseAuth.getUid());

    docRef.update(USERNAME_KEY, username)
            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.d(TAG, "Username DocumentSnapshot Successful"))
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "Error Updating Document: user/uid/username", e));
}
```

(*A typical path to the collection is "users/{userId}/username"*)

**The Problem**: When attempting to update the username field within a users document, the Cloud Function `createUserAccount` has not finished creating/adding the new user document to the database (i.e. An asynchronous issue).

I've considered using rxJava2 to help alleviate this issue, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If there's something you need clarification on, I'll try my best to provide the needed information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the following flow:

1. You call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`
2. A cloud function kicks off and writes some user info to Firestore
3. Locally, you attempt to update the user info to include the 
    username.

But steps 2 and 3 are a race condition, since the cloud function might not be done when you issue the update on the client.

The issue is that the `update()` call depends on the document existing.  If you instead use the `set()` call with the `merge` option in both your client side code and your cloud function, you will avoid this situation.

**Cloud Function**

```
function createUserDoc(userId, data) {
  var userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);

  // Set the user document, creating it if it does not exist
  // and merging with existing data if it does
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
}
```

**Android Code**

```
public void updateUsername(userId, username) {
  Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
  data.put("username", username);

  db.collection("users").document(userId)
          .set(data, SetOptions.merge());
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was definitely the issue, and this works! Could I ask your advice on this:
My app allows users to create a unique username and stores this value in a collection "usernames" with a random UID. I then add two fields, owner with the UID matching to a "user" document and name value with the actual username. Within the "user" document I update the "username" field with the value of the UID of a username in the "usernames" collection. Is this approach efficient when I need to check that a username is available on account creation?

Comment: @N.P I don't quite understand your situation and I think it would be easiest if you asked a new question on StackOverflow about this (which I will be happy to answer)

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to query all the available documents in a collection. (e.g all the documents that exist within a username collection to store only unique usernames).

Comment: @N.P this conversation really needs to be moved to its own question.